# How to set hotkey shortcut "Ctrl + Plus Sign"

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys, menustrip

I need to set shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `"Plus Sign"` for one of the `MenuStrip` menu item.

I prefer to set it NOT programmatically to have an help text block in the right side of menu item:

[image: Screenshot of menu]

But I do not see there such variant to choose. Closest is "OemPlus"

Comment: I cant remember the name of it, but I'm sure you can find it.. there's a property on the menu item that allows you to override the hotkey text with whatever text you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Oemplus` is the right setting. If you don't like the text, change `ShortcutKeyDisplayString` as well, e.g. to `Ctrl++`

[image: Screenshot of Hotkey]

Note that it is called OemPlus and not NumPlus, so does not work for the Numpad plus. Some people don't seem to know where the plus sign is and will try the Numpad plus.

If you need both, you need `KeyPreview = true` and code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Add))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+Numplus");
        return true;
    }
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Oemplus))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+Oemplus");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: but + and - on the numpad works perfectly and no matter there is numlock enabled or disabled. Another one plus is located on the same button as "=". And must not work ofc. So by logic numpad plus and minus is must to work. But they doesn't.

Comment: understood my problem. Thanks. Is it possible to make work both of shortcuts? I mean NUM shortcut + OEM shortcut both.

Comment: @Andrew: I updated the question. You need code then.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171651(v=vs.110).aspx

**To display custom shortcut keys for a menu command**

Set the menu command's ShortcutKeyDisplayString property to the desired keyboard combination, such as `CTRL+SHIFT+S`  and set the `ShowShortcutKeys` property to true.